# R - How to "zoom" on a grid graphics object

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

I was wondering if it is possible to "zoom" in on a plot/table made with grid graphics ?

For example say I created a plot but wanted to focus on the bottom left quarter and thus would zoom in by setting my plotting range to x = c(0,0.5) and y = c(0, 0.5).

The code below is the best I could do which mostly works however it can't account for fixed size elements such as the margin panels in ggplot. You will notice that if you change the scaling to say `xrange = c(0,0.1)` &  `yrange = c(0,0.1)` that the ggplot margin panels stay the exact same size and push the ggplot points out of alignment with the grid.text elements I overlaid.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(grid)


PLOT <- ggplot(iris , aes(x = Sepal.Width , y = Sepal.Length)) + geom_point()
GPLOT <- ggplotGrob(PLOT)

COORDS <- expand.grid( c(0:10) , c(0:10)) %>% 
    as_data_frame() %>%
    setNames(c("x" , "y")) %>% 
    mutate( label = paste0( x , "," ,y )) %>% 
    mutate( x= x/10 , y = y / 10)


xrange <- c(0, 0.5)
yrange <- c(0, 0.5)

grid.newpage()
pushViewport(
    viewport(
        x = 0.5 + (0.5 - mean(xrange)) / diff(xrange) , 
        y = 0.5 + (0.5 -  mean(yrange)) / diff(yrange), 
        width  = 1/diff(xrange) , 
        height = 1/diff(yrange)
    )
)

grid.draw(GPLOT)
grid.text( label = COORDS$label , x = COORDS$x , y = COORDS$y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Would it be okay to overlay the `grid.text` elements on the plot panel only? If so, something like this might work.

```
PLOT <- ggplot(iris , aes(x = Sepal.Width , y = Sepal.Length)) + geom_point()
GPLOT <- ggplotGrob(PLOT)

COORDS <- expand.grid( c(0:10) , c(0:10)) %>% 
    as_data_frame() %>%
    setNames(c("x" , "y")) %>% 
    mutate( label = paste0( x , "," ,y )) %>% 
    mutate( x= x/10 , y = y / 10)


xrange <- c(0, .5)
yrange <- c(0, .5)



grid.newpage()

# Draw the labels on the plot panel
GPLOT$layout$clip = "off" # so that labels on the boundary get drawn
grid.draw(GPLOT)
downViewport("panel.6-4-6-4")   # The panel viewport - current.vpTree()
grid.text(label = COORDS$label , x = COORDS$x , y = COORDS$y)

grab = grid.grab()  # Grab that plot

# Then proceed as before - zoom into this plot
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(
    vp = viewport(
        x = 0.5 + (0.5 - mean(xrange)) / diff(xrange) , 
        y = 0.5 + (0.5 -  mean(yrange)) / diff(yrange), 
        width  = 1/diff(xrange) , 
        height = 1/diff(yrange), name = "Size"
    )
)

grid.draw(grab)
```

[image]